# javascript - set speed / pace

Tags: javascript

I have a script which loops through an array of words, but how do I add a speed element to this?

```
words = ["Doe", "Ray", "Mee"]; 
count = words.length;
currentWord = random(0, parseInt(count)); 
words[parseInt(currentWord)];
```

Comment: what do you mean by "speed" element? speed for what? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: aye, speed to which element ? and why speed ?

Comment: if count==3 and currentWord==3 i get an error as there is no words[3]

Comment: can I change the pace at which they are displayed?

Comment: I don't see anything displaying in that code.

Comment: mmm....@green_arrow, still can't get what you are trying to do. could you write what is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delay the execution of each interation of your loop, have a look at `setInterval` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)) and `setTimeout` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)).